# RDS MySQL Connection via external SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, ssh-tunnel

I have a MySQL database running in AWS and I would like to set up a SSH tunnel into it. I cannot use AWS EC2 instance as a remote host due to internal work constrains and can only use a jumpbox hosted outside of this RDS's VPC.

1. Is it an acceptable practice?
2. Is the connection's IP address going to be defined by the jumpbox? So it's IP address can be whitelisted in AWS Security Groups.

Comment: The VPCs are peered?

Comment: Not peered, jumbox is hosted in a separate on-premise network (not AWS VPC)

Comment: So the RDS is a public database, with public IP accessible over the internet?

Comment: RDS is a public database, but public access is restricted to a range of IP addresses

Comment: You could restrict the IP address to that of your corporate network -- it would 'appear' to come from a single IP address where the corporate network connects to the Internet. So, instead of having a jump box, your whole corporate network could be the 'jump box'. If you are remote, you would first VPN into the corporate network, then access the database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohnRotenstein, it is a good solution in theory, but unfortunately does not work for me because when users access the database remotely (physical corporate router or software VPN) not all traffic is forced to go via corporate proxy, hence defaulting to a non-whitelisted IP address (outside of whitelisted corporate range). The reason why I am trying the bastion host route is to solve this problem.

Comment: If your Jump Box is created in your corporate network, then its IP address will 'appear' to be the IP address of where your corporate network connects to the Internet. The easiest way to discover it is to connect to the Jump Box, then `curl https://icanhazip.com/` -- it will show you the Public IP address being used. Then, add that to the Security Group for the Amazon RDS database.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it an acceptable practice?

Usually you would use ssh tunnels to connect to a private subnet. But having public RDS with strictly limited allowed IP addresses is also good.

> Is the connection's IP address going to be defined by the jumpbox? So it's IP address can be whitelisted in AWS Security Groups.

Yes. But if the IP address is not static, anytime it changes you will have to update the SGs.